# Ubuntu 10.04 + ThinClient PC Limited click options

Tags: server

I have following situation.

1 big server in which Ubuntu 14.04 is installed with GUI and which supports VM

Then we installed VM and created 2 sub VM machine inside it.

both are having Ubuntu 10.04.04 its

Now we need that people from local network (they all have THIN Client PC) can log to Server GUI (but only have only 1 Icon on their desktop)

So Worker Group in Factory is named (user = worker) and they should have only 1 thing to click and that is program  icon.

Rest all dropdown, menu options, all things should be barred/block for that particular group.

How can I do that.

Can some please help me, I tried searching this, but I am not able to find solutions, probably b/c. I am unaware to this terminology.

Thanks in advance.

Good Day.

Comment: Why did you install 10.04 ?? thats not supported anymore.. But this question might still be considered as valid as you are running 14.04 as host.

Comment: I install Ubuntu 10.04 because my software runs only on that with Python 2.6 and lots of other dependability any order to run that we are we we have to have this OS so if you can please help us it would be much appreciated I don't have any other choice thank you sir

Comment: Can anyone help